# javascript validation of control array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing an application in which end user can create 'n' number of textbox on runtime. If any user will demand 'n' number of textboxex then i have used control array e.g.

```
Enter the data: <input type="text" name="txtData[]" id="txtData1" /><br/>
Enter the data: <input type="text" name="txtData[]" id="txtData2" /><br/>
```

In whole application name based validation is used (http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml). I am unable to validate above functionality using this validation.
Is any way to validate control array?

Comment: You don't have valid markup, you have an `id` attribute twice *per element*, and an ID needs to be unique in the entire page.

Comment: Is "txtData[]" a valid name for a form element? Doesn't look right.

Comment: All code is written with 'txtData[]' and execute properly. Only validation is remained.

Comment: Arrayish names are prefectly valid and required if you send the data to a PHP script which should create an array.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use a modern validation framework, e.g. the [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). Just from the fact that the one you linked uses `language="JavaScript"` instead of `type="text/javascript"` it's probably old or not very good.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, does it validate when you add the correct index to you names?

```
Enter the data: <input type="text" name="txtData[1]" id="txtData1" /><br/>
Enter the data: <input type="text" name="txtData[2]" id="txtData2" /><br/>
```

And you should maybe start the numbering from 0 if want to loop more easily trough your form data after submit. So:

```
Enter the data: <input type="text" name="txtData[0]" id="txtData0" /><br/>
Enter the data: <input type="text" name="txtData[1]" id="txtData1" /><br/>
```